# How to get sound data from all sounds you play at the smae time? (actionscript flash)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, audio, mxml

So If I play one sound I use

```
sound = new Sound(); ...
sound.addEventListener( SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData);
sound.play();
```

And so I'll get data, but If I have 20 sounds playing and I want to get data from the sound I here as a resalt of data mix  of all that sounds... How to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(). It won't fire an event during each sample, but it will create a ByteArray with all the sound data mixed together. You can then manipulate that data.